# Running Sinatra app with Mongrel on Windows

Tags: ruby, sinatra, mongrel

I'd like to start a Sinatra app from Mongrel on Windows, rather than Sinatra starting Mongrel in the background.

Is there a simple way to use Mongrel for Sinatra?  It's looking for a rails app by default.

Edit: Suggested solution is to simply run a VMWare or SunBox with real Linux and deal with the corporate issues that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://sinatra-book.gittr.com/.

FastCGI is the chapter you're looking for within the page, because that's what mongrel is

Comment: The documentation no longer exists at that link.

Answer (score -1):

if you have a rake config, like config.ru
then install thin gem
then
thin -p 3000 -r config.ru
I think.
-r